# How to get the current date and time in specific format in Shell

Tags: shell, unix

I just want to get the system current time using below format in shell

```
  Expected Format:
  2019-02-14T08:08:12.300Z
```

I tried below piece of script but It returned something different.

```
  CURRENTDATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"`
  echo $CURRENTDATE
```

**Output**

```
   2019-02-27 01:22:57
```

I just ran date command in my linux box and got below response back:

```
   -bash-3.2$ date
   Wed Feb 27 01:43:26 PST 2019
```

We are passing the above output as input JSON file. But this output is not accepted by our JSON. So I just want to pass the date and time format in the above specified format (Expected Format).

Comment: `300Z` means 3 hours ahead of UTC, which will be some Asian country

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use:

```
dt=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%T.%zZ')
echo "$dt"
```

```
2019-02-27T04:35:56.-0500Z
```

Also note use of `--iso-8601=seconds`:

```
date --iso-8601=seconds
```

```
2019-02-27T04:37:29-05:00
```

Comment: I think it looks like everything same except the last 4 digits are negative  -0500Z

Comment: My output shows `-0500Z` because of my current timezone. You will get different timezone. btw what is your zone?

Comment: -bash-3.2$ date
Wed Feb 27 01:43:26 PST 2019

Comment: Then use: `TZ=America/Los_Angeles date '+%Y-%m-%dT%T.%zZ'` but PST will also be negative offset since UTC is ahead by 8 hrs from PST

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this one like

```
currentDate=$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
echo $currentDate
```

OutPut :-

```
2022-07-12T18:05:27Z
```